# Extract from List of Counters Common Keys

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a list of counters as shown below:

```
List1: [Counter({22.99: 1}), Counter({12.011: 2, 15.999: 2}), 
Counter({12.011: 7})]
List2: [Counter({12.011: 15, 15.999: 1})]
```

I want to find the common keys between both lists of counters. The following solution works for Python 3.0 but not 2.7. Would be great if you could suggest a compatible solution for 2.7.

```
np.array(list(set().union(rhs, *lhs)))[:, None]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
def get_keys(l):
    return set([sub for x in l for sub in x.keys()])

>>> get_keys(l1) & get_keys(l2)
{12.011, 15.999}
```